# Only accept visits from a defined referrer URL?

Tags: php, web, paypal

I have a Paypal button on my website and I have a page that Paypal will direct the user to once they're done paying. How can I make sure that the only people coming to this page are referred by paypal.com?

Comment: Paypal doesn't have a secure way for you to confirm your payments. I know that you can confirm payments using authorize.net. Since your using paypal you probably know this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to get the referrer and check it against paypal.com

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$referer_parts = parse_url($referer);
if($referer_parts['host'] == "paypal.com") {
    echo "good";
} else {
    echo "bad";
}
```

**NOTE:**

> 'HTTP_REFERER'
>
> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

I don't think there's any reliable way of checking where the user came from. I could simply go to a paypal page and simply run `location.href='http://yoursite.com/yourpage.php'` or insert a link into the DOM that I could click and you wouldn't have any way of knowing.

The only way, I think, would be if paypal sent the customer to your site with a unique code that you could verify on your end. This way, the only people who can get to your page are ones who have a code.

Comment: Why not some form of `if` statement? I can modify code but can't write them worth to save my life, yet I figure that's how I would do it, if I knew how to write code from scratch.

Comment: @AdamSack I didn't include code because it's not a reliable way (there isn't one as far as I know) of doing it and I don't want Colby to just copy/paste thinking it's foolproof. Plus, my answer is too long for a comment. Anyway, I've included code now.

Comment: Did it cross your mind to have paypal return the user with a unique ID so that you can verify that the user initiated the request?

Comment: No worries, man. I don't know how paypal works so I wasn't sure that's possible but if it is, that's the way to go.